# Lighting up LED lights on Arduino tank using Arduino transmitter

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making an Arduino tank using the motor shield, more of a recon tank as it has no gun. And I'm using one Arduino board as the receiver and controller of the tank and the other as the transmitter. I'm thinking of adding lights to the build and want to remotely operated them. I don't know where to look at or start. Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a free code writing service.

Comment: I am very sorry gre_gor I didn't know that you would take this the wrong way. I am just new to this Arduino thing and wanted since guidance. If you wish, I will delete this question

Comment: You said, "Can someone just send me the code".  So I don't think he took that wrongly.  We are not a free code writing service.

Comment: @Ronitbal - Change the last line of you question to "I don't know how to start, please can some one tell what I need to look at?" and people should be OK with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Im going to see your question with good eyes and help you out giving you the properly guidance. With no sarcasm.

First of all you just would do some google searchs using the correct words.

To achieve the correct words you need to enumerate important things just doing the following quastions.

What do I have?

```
Arduino, Led
```

What do I want?

```
Controlling Led Remotely
```

So with these couple of question I could achieve the following sentence:

```
controlling led arduino remotely
```

This gave me the following good and usefull link with source code:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Control-LEDs-with-a-Remote-Control/

Now you can improve your serach and come back here, bringing us what you have done so far with a far more accurated techinical question like:

```
What is the best way to controlling LED remotely in the given situation?
```

And go on.

The most important thing to know is how to separate requirements from impediments. I think now you are fair well introduced about how to use this very good resource.

Comment: Before you can operate LEDs remotely, do you know how to write a program to make a switch turn on a LED on the same board?  Then the next step is make the switch on board 1 turn on the light on board two.